# Why the ContextMenu right mouse click on ListView items is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, contextmenu

At the top of form1:

```
private ContextMenuStrip contextmenustrip1 = new ContextMenuStrip();
```

Then:

```
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ListView listView = sender as ListView;
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ListViewItem item = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                contextmenustrip1.Show(listView, e.Location);
            }
        }
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Cut");
        menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CutAction);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new MenuItem("Copy");
        menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CopyAction);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new MenuItem("Paste");
        menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(PasteAction);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
    }
}
```

When i make click on item using a break point it's getting to the event but the right mouse click is not working but for sure it's not showing the menus the Cut Copy Paste.

I want to make that when i make right click on item in the listView it will show the menu for the current item. Not sure if i should first make mousedown first or some other event not sure what's more logic. But the idea is to show the menu per right mouse click on item.

Comment: Create/design the menu in the forms designer and simply assign it to the listview's ContextMenuStrip property. It will do everything itself - none of that code is needed

Comment: Why you are using both `ContextMenu` and `ContextMenuStrip`?

Comment: Probably you want to add those items to your `contextmenustrip1` and created a new `ContextMenu` by mistake. You don't need to create that `ContextMenu`. Just follow what @Plutonix said using designer, or if for any reason you want to use code to initialize that `ContextMenuStrip`, just add some new `ToolStripMenuItem` in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything of the above. Simply, call the `Click` event of the menu item.

Firstly, set the View Mode of your `ListView` to **Details** and then set the `ContextMenuStrip` Property of the `ListView` to **contextMenuStrip1**.

**ContextMenuStrip**:

> The shortcut menu to display when the user right clicks the control.

So, say for *Cut* menu, call the `Click` event `CutToolStripMenuItem`. Similarly, call the events for `Copy` and `Paste` as well and add your code.

```
private void CutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem LItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            //Your code                  
        }
    }
}
```

[image: right_click]

Comment: I need to add items to the contextMenuStrip1 ? Like Cut ? And how do i create the event CutToolStripMenuItem_Click ? Or should i make it all by code add items and create the events ?

Comment: @TheLostLostit hope you are able to understand this [Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wUF4I.png) :)

Comment: Working. Thank you.